# Looping through or lapply on list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, loops, lapply

I do have some grasp on how to use lapply to, say, change the names of variables in several dataframes in a list. However, I am looking to carry out a slightly (but only slightly) more complicated operation.

More specifically, I am looking to calculate the mean growth rates for several entities. The growth rate have already been calculated, so I just need to perfor the following operations on all dataframes

```
for (i in 1:13) {
  growth.type[,i] <- tapply(growth[,8+i] , growth$type, mean, na.rm = TRUE) 
}
```

This creates a new dataframe (`growth.type`) that includes the mean of all several hundred growth rates in the original dataframe (`growth`), by `type`.

Now, I would like to do this to several dataframes (like `growth`) and put them into new dataframes (like `growth.type`).

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Put all data.frames you wish to process in a list

```
xy <- list(growth1, growth2, growth3, ...)
```

and then apply a custom function to this `xy` object.

```
customFunction <- function(.data) {
  for (i in 1:13) {
    growth.type[,i] <- tapply(.data[,8+i] , .data$type, mean, na.rm = TRUE) 
  }
  growth.type # this is the object which will be returned when function finishes
}
```

then just do

```
out <- lapply(xy, FUN = customFunction)
```

If you want to combine the result of `lapply`, you can use `do.call`, e.g. `do.call("rbind", out)`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I guess what you are hinting at by the last sentence is how to store the data.frames that come out. Could you elaborate a little on how to do that? When I do `out <- lapply(xy, FUN = customFunction)` I get a list of empty dataframes, even though the function works fine on one dataframe alone.

Comment: @pApaAPPApapapa The easiest way would be to have a reproducible example. If you can't provide one, try putting `browser()` just before the last line of `growth.type`. The execution will stop there and you can inspect objects. To run the code to next element, type `c` (continue) into the console. To run only one line press enter or type `n` (next).